# Do we see a victim of Hemalurgy who isn't killed?

Tags: cosmere, mistborn

Someone took [notes](http://www.17thshard.com/forum/topic/1729-a-late-breaking-report/#entry30533) from an interview with Brandon Sanderson:

> One does not have to kill someone with Hemalurgy to charge a spike, but it rips off a large part of the soul. The person would not be the same.

Do we ever see such a person in the *Mistborn* or *Wax and Wayne* books?

Comment: I would say probably not. I read all of them and I don't recall any such person. They'd be a bit like a drab from *Warbreaker*, but probably in a worse state.

Comment: I've found several quotes from different places where Sanderson says someone *could* survive being a victim of Hemalurgy. If there was an actual example in his books, one would have expected him to have mentioned it at least once.

Comment: I think it was mentioned in the last Mistborn book that the Set has advanced their Hemalurgy to this point, but we only get shown the powers they stole, not the victims.  Or maybe it's just a word-of-author I'm remembering, not sure (could even be what you linked).

Comment: Had a sudden thought that we have had an example of someone with large parts of their soul ripped out, just that it was the kandra, not a hemalurgy victim.  MeLaan getting her spikes removed - unable to control herself, moving only on instinct, half-mad, and screaming on the inside - that feels about right for what should happen.  May or may not be terribly relevant though.

Comment: I explained a few things in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **Yes.**

In *The Lost Metal*, in chapter 47, during

> Marasi's scene in the Set's tunnels,

there is indeed someone who is stabbed with a Hemalurgic spike and survives.

Quote from chapter 47 of *The Lost Metal*, emphasis mine:

> At a nod from [the scientist], the assistants threaded the long spike through the skin of the [victim]'s upper back. Almost like they were sewing with a six inch needle ... "Roughly five percent Invested," [the scientist] reported to Entrone. "And as you can see, **the subject is still alive.** We've essentially excised a piece of the soul and stored it in the metal."

Answer (score 6):

### I don't think so

A living victim of Hemalurgy would be very noticeable. Hemalurgy violently rips away a portion of one's Spiritweb (essentially, the soul).

[According to Sanderson:](https://mobile.twitter.com/BrandSanderson/status/695365263240212480)

> It IS possible to spike someone without killing them.  But they'd
>   never be the same.  It would be worse than being a drab.

A Drab, as we recall, is someone who has given away all their Breath. Breath is the primary form of Investiture (magic) on Nalthis, a world whose deity, Endowment, focuses on the gifting (fully voluntary or otherwise) of Investiture to others. Drabs have thus given away part of their Spiritweb, and are in a similar situation to victims of Hemalurgy (though less serious).

From this we can gather that someone who survived being spiked would probably have a very flat affect, a seriously weakened immune system, and so forth.

To my knowledge, no character of this sort is mentioned in *Mistborn*.

In addition, only the the Lord Ruler, the Steel Inquisition and the Set (the organization run by Suit and Sequence in the *Wax and Wayne* books) have employed Hemalurgy on a large scale thus far, and all had an interest in secrecy, and no benefit to leaving their victims alive to tell tales.